# Android ListView not refreshing after change cursor

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter, mergecursor

the following code is used to populate an endless ListView.
When the user reach the end of the list, the app call the async task to get more items, then on post execute the new cursor is returned and merged with the previous.
The problem is this code does not work on ICS and Jelly Bean, but works on Froyo and Gingerbread.
On ICS and JellyBean the listview gets empty, but if you log cursor size you get the size of the merged cursor.

```
Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[2];   
//actual cursor   
cursors[0] = resourceCursor.getCursor();   
//new cursor returned by async task   
cursors[1] = result;   
MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);   
resourceCursor.changeCursor(mergeCursor);
```

Comment: Hello @soynerdito thanks for the answer, i tried after the change cursor but with no luck...

Comment: Another developer with the same problem: http://buradabuldum.blogspot.pt/2012/01/android-developers-mergecursor-broken.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found a solution, seems an ungly solution, but it works.
On my research all the problems seemed to address to an issue after Honeycumb, so i changed the API Level to 11, to get swapCursor available, and then, on my code:

```
Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[2];   
//actual cursor   
cursors[0] = resourceAdapterCursor.getCursor();   
//new cursor returned by async task   
cursors[1] = result;   
MergeCursor mergeCursor = new MergeCursor(cursors);   
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
    resourceAdapterCursor.swapCursor(mergeCursor);
} else {
    resourceAdapterCursor.changeCursor(mergeCursor);
}
```

Thanks!
Best regards.
Rodrigo

Comment: But don't forget, that swapCursor is not closing the old cursor.